# Reclaiming disk space in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ext4, vmware, disk

In VMWare the hard disks took `13.6 GB`,

[image]

But with df, only `5.8 GB` is occupied

[image]

I don't quite get it. This Virtual Machine has no snapshots, and I already clicked on `refresh` button in VMWare Fusion

Is there anyway to reclaim the disk space in Ubuntu (ext4) ?

Comment: Generally with dynamically allocated virtual disks, they only consume the amount of space actually used. The exception is when data is deleted, you don't get that space back.